# Why is a quoted empty array not an argument, but a quoted empty string is?

Tags: bash

Consider:

```
# double quotes make empty variables count as args

emptyvar=""
printf %s%s%sEND $emptyvar a b c
echo ""
printf %s%s%sEND "$emptyvar" a b c

echo ""
echo ""

# but an empty array does not count, even with double quotes

empty=()
printf %s%s%sEND ${empty[@]} a c b
echo ""
printf %s%s%sEND "${empty[@]}" a b c
```

which outputs:

```
abcEND
abENDcEND

acbEND
abcEND
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9NCsIwEEb3OcVHq6DgFQoudOsFxMUkRlu0Sc1PpYhnj7GmFaHILGbxHswbTrYMIcdRe36VuHntpEVNFwlZN65DS6aiiCyE9sqBLMicLWM9jrTIMtaYSrkT5vY9290Gs4GCwCGYFKXGlJiNZpbU0R02y8F9PKxSERlDXQyOSUq7T9YKspUK98qVv6@kzmKxnIh89Gy/PjzjbQH@L/PrptAQXg)

I understand the first example.

I understand that in the 2nd example the double quotes are somehow forcing the empty string to be considered an arg, because of how word splitting works -- but I'm hazy on the details.

I *think* the 3rd example is working similar to the first: it just gets processed as whitespace during word splitting.

And I'm unclear why arrays are treated specially in the 4th case.

I'd like an explanation of what is happening under the hood to understand it better, along with any relevant quotes from man bash (I wasn't able to find anything explaining this behavior, but probably missed it).

Comment: Why does the second example print the extra `cEND` at the end?  Because "the format is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments".

Comment: I was curious about this too.  Afaict, if it needs to be re-used, it gets re-used in total, not partially.  But this specific point isn't documented in the GNU bash manual -- only the general point about re-use that you quoted.

Comment: The pattern gets reused in total, but for the second time round, there is only one argument left (the `c`). So it prints `c`, then nothing, then nothing for the three `%s`, then `END` at the end.

Comment: Yes, I actually understood all that.  My only question about the 2nd example is why the quotes there create an empty string argument but the quotes in the 4th example do not.  oguz's answer mostly clears it up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man bash`:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`.  The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.  **If subscript is `@` or `*`, the word expands to all members of name.  These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes.** If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable, and `${name[@]}` expands each element of name to a separate word.  **When there are no array members, `${name[@]}` expands to nothing.**

Comment: Thanks oguz.  To me, though, that leaves more to be explained because "nothing" isn't defined.  Couldn't one say that the empty string is "nothing"?  Why does it consume an argument while the quoted empty array does not?

Comment: Empty string is a thing while nothing is not. *`${name[@]}` expands each element of `name` to a separate word* explain it well imo.

Comment: ... and `"${name[0]}"` *does* expand to an empty-string argument.  You can get your desired effect by initialising your array with `$name[0]=""`, then `"${name[@]}"` expands to an empty string.

Comment: Think of it this way: an "empty" string is the one-byte sequence `\0`.  An array is not a string, but a collection of strings, and that *collection* can be truly empty. So when we say that `"${empty[@]}"` expands to nothing, we aren't saying it expands to some null-terminated string; it is literally the *absence* of any null-terminated strings.

Comment: Arrays themselves do not "exist" in any objective sense. Rather, names marked with the array attribute behave as a collection of strings, and that collection can be truly empty.